# Is Java MulticastSocket threadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, multicastsocket

I have two threads.
First one sends datagrams with a MulticastSocket in loop; the second thread receives datagrams using the same instance of MulticastSocket in loop.

It seems to be working properly, but I'm still in doubts.

Can these two threads use the same instance of MulticastSocket? Is MulticastSocket threadsafe in respect send/receive methods invocation?

Comment: I doubt it would matter whether the socket is multicast or not.

Comment: OK. Can two threads use the same socket to read/write from/to it simultaneously?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both send and receive DatagramSocket methods are synchronized on the sending/receiving datagram packet. In other words if you are using a same datagram packet to send and receive from two different threads these two methods will be synchronized as they are going to use the same object as a synchronization token.

It's much easier to understand once looked at the source code of [DatagramSocket](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.java.html).

Comment: That's all. If I use the same instance of DatagramPacket then I cannot send and receive the DatagramPacket simultaneously from two different threads.

Comment: No, you are not able to simultaneously send and receive the same instance of DatagramPacket from two different threads.

Answer (score 2):

`DatagramSocket` [is thread safe](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/DatagramSocket.java#578), `MulticastSocket` is a derivative class, in consequence `MulticastSocket.send` is thread-safe, since access is being serialized by a [synchronized block](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/DatagramSocket.java#580).

Comment: Well, the link indeed says that DatagramSocket is threadsafe. However, I cannot confirm it looking at DatagramSocket source.

Comment: Just as Boris pointed below, at DatagramSocket#send lines 574-6 you can see that send(DatagramPacket) is synchronized over its argument, while the whole DatagramSocket#receive method is marked as synchronized.

Comment: Th link above is merely a copy of posts that were originally made in the Sun Java forums.

Comment: Good catch, changed the link to point to the `DatagramSocket` source as it was doing 5 years ago.