# Is MulticastSocket.send() reentrant?

Tags: java, send, multicastsocket

I have 2 threads that want to invoke:

`multicastSocket.send(dP1)` and

`multicastSocket.send(dP2)`

respectively, where `dP1` and `dP2` are different `DatagramPacket` objects, and `multicastSocket` is the shared instance of MulticastSocket.

I don't understand if concurrency problems may happen on `multicastSocket,` if the threads call `send()` in the same moment.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108644/is-java-multicastsocket-threadsafe

Comment: Alex, looking at the bottom of the question you linked, it is said that send is not a synchronized method. So concurrency problems may eventually happen? However I guess this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: edit: title now says what the question is really asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- DatagramSocket reads and writes are independent of each other.
- DatagramSocket writes are atomic so they are thread-safe.
- DatagramSocket reads are synchronized by Java and they are also
  atomic at the OS level so again they are thread-safe.
- MulticastSocket inherits these methods from DatagramSocket so the same applies to it.