# MulticastSocket join/leave group, send, receive thread-safety

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, multicast

I was reasoning about multicast socket thread-safety in my application. First of all I've multiple threads sharing the same multicast socket instance, this multicast socket is used to join different groups on the same port. Here are my questions:

1. Do I have to synchronize calls to `joinGroup()` and `leaveGroup()` methods?
2. Do I have to synchronize calls to `send()` and `receive()` methods which uses always new istance of datagram packet as parameter?

Here's a code example of the 2nd question:

```
/* SEND METHOD EXAMPLE. */
    DatagramPacket sndPckt = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, groupAddr,port);
    try{
        multicastSocket.send(sndPckt);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        /* Error handling. */
    }
/* RECEIVE METHOD EXAMPLE. */
    DatagramPacket recv = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        try{
            multicastSocket.receive(recv);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            /* Error handling. */
        }
```

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108644/is-java-multicastsocket-threadsafe) but it talks about using the same`Datagram Packet`.
I've also tested my application but I didn't found any race condition or inconsistency but I'm not 100% sure that there usage is thread-safe.

Comment: What does the documentation say about thread-safety of those methods?

Comment: @Kayaman nothing?

Comment: You're correct, young grasshopper.

Comment: The documentation does not alway say everything, don't you think?

Comment: Sometimes the documentation says a lot when it says nothing. Other times, the opposite.

Comment: @Kayaman what's your opinion about these answers?

Comment: That you're getting some grade A answers when both EJP and Stephen C are involved. Not to mention that they agree!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javadocs do not say whether or not `MulticastSocket` is thread-safe or not, but reading the sourcecode indicates that it is.

1. The `joinGroup()` and `leaveGroup()` methods are wrappers for `native` calls, which are (in turn) wrappers for system calls.  All system calls are thread-safe, at least in respect to data held in kernel-space.  (If they weren't, that would be a potential security flaw.)  My reading of the code is that `joinGroup()` and `leaveGroup()` do not update any user-space data.
2. The `send()` and `receive()` methods synchronize on their `DataPacket` arguments to ensure that two threads using the same `DataPacket` can do so safely.  Apart from the data packet objects, these methods don't update any shared socket state in user-space, and (as above) we can assume that kernel-space data is thread-safe.

EJP reasons that these syscalls are atomic (by design) and therefore thread-safe.  That is correct<sup>1</sup>.  However, thread safety in user-space (i.e. before and after the syscalls, or when two syscalls share a user-space buffer) also needs to be considered.

---

<sup>1 - at least to my understanding.  I couldn't find a definitive source which says which syscalls are atomic by design.</sup>

Comment: Agreed. I was more concerned about reading my ancient Sun post into the record here.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I have to synchronize calls to joinGroup() and leaveGroup() methods?

No.

> Do I have to synchronize calls to send() and receive() methods which uses always new istance of datagram packet as parameter?

No.

- `DatagramSocket` reads and writes are independent of each other.
- `DatagramSocket` writes are atomic at the OS level, so they are thread-safe.
- `DatagramSocket` reads are synchronized by Java, and they are also
  atomic at the OS level, so again they are thread-safe.
- `MulticastSocket` inherits its I/O methods from `DatagramSocket`.
- `joinGroup()/leaveGroup()` are also atomic at the OS level.

Lest I am accused of [plagiarism](https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/is-datagramsocket-thread-safe.150685/) I will state that that link is itself an unauthorized copy of material I originally wrote on the Sun Java forums decades ago.

Comment: I suggest you get authorization from yourself before you post links to your content.